# Does my derivation work?

Tags: limits, special-functions

I've been totally engaged with exponential integrals for a while. I came across to this limit in my work. I started to calculate the limit as below: currently, I am not sure about my handouts. would you please check it out ? I'll will be happy for any suggestions. ( **If someone else has asked this question before or this question could be considered as a duplicated, Inform me, I will delete it immediately** ).

$$lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty}e^{-x}E_{1}(x)=?$$

These are my calculations:

$$e^{-x}E_{1}(x)=-Ce^{-x}-e^{-2x}\ln x-e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}\ln{ t} \ dt\ \ \ [1]$$

Here after, I am feeling uncertain !

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\ln t dt=-C \ \ \ [2]$$

Where, C is Euler constant.Therefore, we can simplify the limit as:

$$lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty}e^{-x}E_{1}(x)=-lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty}e^{-2x}\ln x$$

Using Lhopital we will get:

$$lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty}e^{-x}E_{1}(x)=\frac{-1}{\infty}=0$$

---

**Reference:**

For $[1]$ , $[2]$, look Gradshteyn Eq.$8.212$, and  Eq.$4.331$, respectively.
Thanks

Comment: could you add what $E_(x)$  is supposed to be? an editing advice, you better use $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ and also $\ln$

Comment: @user190080 (+1) I am not fully understood you, however, if you have question about the $E_{1}$, it is exponential integral

Comment: I mean your $\LaTeX$, as I said, it is just an editing advice